# ORM/MDA/UML tool for VB6

Tags: orm, vb6, uml, reverse-engineering, mda

I know of Rational Rose and we have got Rational Rose 6.

But I am looking for some other tools which are more usable, which do not complain that they are not running in Windows 98/2000 (when installed and run in WinXP) and has got better features as compared to Rational Rose 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/products/ea/features.html) lists Visual Basic (as distinct from VB.Net) as supported.

Comment: It does list VB but there is no reference that it can handle reverse engineering from VB Project.

Any way I will download it and test for more first hand experience with it.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/products/ea/index.html). It's not expensive and does a lot of things well.

Answer (score 1):

Enterprise Architect does reverse engineering and code generation for VB6

Answer (score 0):

I did check out Enterprise Architect on SpareX's web site but could not find any reference stating that it handles reverse engineering or code generation for VB6.

Comment: I know this is an old thread but the supporting information re Enterprise Architect and VB6 can be found here: http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/10/software_engineering/reverseengineersourcecode.html