# Visual Basic 6.0 Code generator

Tags: vb6, code-generation

I have a MS Sql 2005 Database , and I want to generate Visual BAsic code of Data Entity Class, I search the web but I can find a tool that I want. If you any information or link please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've heard that [Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com/products/ea/index.html) has an entity/ORM framework generator for VB6, but I can't say for sure.  I suggest you start looking there. [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367552/orm-mda-uml-tool-for-vb6)

I had to roll my own at work, but it's copyrighted by the company so I wouldn't be able to post it here.  I can give you a brief synopsis if you want to try it yourself:

- I created a "base class" for an entity (VB6 doesn't support inheritance, so this was actually a "wrapped" base class)

  - Has Methods like Insert, Update, LoadByPrimaryKey, etc.
- I created a similar "base class" for a collection of entities.

  - Supports simple .Where and .OrderBy methods that build a query
- I created a code generator that pulled a list of tables from the database

  - It generates a module for each table with an Enum listing each column name as an ID, and lookup tables to go from column enum to column name, and back
  - It generates an entity class for each table that wraps the base entity, and has property setters/getters corresponding to each column name
  - It generates an entity collection class for each table that wraps the base collection class

Comment: With these instructions you may implement a code generator using the ABSE approach. Download the AtomWeaver IDE at http://www.atomweaver.com and give it a try. It cannot read from a DB at this time, but you can quickly create a model of your own DB and then generate it there.